# function works but gives errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following function works perfectly. However it gives errors in console, and prevents jqueryui from working.

```
function removenonbtwchars(input){

    input = input.toUpperCase();
    input = input.replace(/\W/g, '');
    input = input.substring(0,16);

    return input;
}
```

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined scripts_V2.js:1924
removenonbtwchars scripts_V2.js:1924
(anonymous function) scripts_V2.js:1934
fire jquery-1.9.1.js:1037
self.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.js:1148
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.9.1.js:433
completed
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: The error is self explanatory. `input` is `undefined` when passed to the function.

Comment: The problem is probably where the function is called : you pass it undefined.

Comment: Let's start with kicking in the open door. Apparently your `input` variable is `undefined`

Comment: *"The following function works perfectly."* No, it doesn't, that's observational error. If you're getting that error, that function is failing on its first line, never completes, and interrupts the processing of whatever called it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, that's probably the intended behavior.

Comment: or may be it is called twice once with the value another time with undefined.... lot of unkowns

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Smart man.

Comment: Add a logging statement in the method as the first line `console.log('input', input); console.trace()` and see the console for the logged messages

Comment: As a side note on your code., did you know you can append functions like this: `return input.toUpperCase().replace(/\W/g, '').substring(0,16);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call this function with some `string` in it.

```
var input = removenonbtwchars("some thing");
```

if you are calling it with some variable try this

```
var input = '';
if ( $.trim(data) != '' ) {
    input = removenonbtwchars(data);
}
```

but remember that the variable `data` should be `string` because `toUpperCase()` is a method of string class

Comment: Thanks this helped me find the problem, the function was indeed called on a page where no string was inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter versions that returns an empty string when you pass a falsy value (like `undefined`):

```
function removenonbtwchars(input){
    return input ? input.toUpperCase().replace(/\W/g, '').substring(0,16) : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met almost the  same error, finally I found that

I didn't  insert "()" between "}" and ");" where in the end of the definition  of the object which own the method .

Comment: Since it's *almost* the same error, do you think this might be a solution to the OP's problem with his or her function?